# window.open React Native WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a code that open new tab in the browser

`window.open`

But when I view the website inside React native webview, it didn't open a window. How can I do this inside webview?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

webview doesnot provide window option, as it is not a browser, so you have make change in your code for react-native by applying checks of platform or other.